# How to use pre_create_historical_record signal in django-simple-history?

Tags: django

I am using [django-simple-history](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest) to save history of data. I want to save an extra field value to each history model before it is saved. I found the reference code in documentation mentioned above but cant use it. Please help.

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from simple_history.signals import (
    pre_create_historical_record,
    post_create_historical_record
)

@receiver(pre_create_historical_record)
def pre_create_historical_record_callback(sender, **kwargs):
    print("Sent before saving historical record")

@receiver(post_create_historical_record)
def post_create_historical_record_callback(sender, **kwargs):
    print("Sent after saving historical record")
```

**apps.py** file

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class LogAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'log_app'
    def ready(self):
        import log_app.signals
```

**signals.py** file

```
from simple_history.signals import (pre_create_historical_record, post_create_historical_record)


@receiver(pre_create_historical_record)
def pre_create_historical_record_callback(sender, **kwargs):
    print("signal is running")
    history_instance = kwargs['history_instance']
```

Comment: This is defined in a `signals.py` file I assume? Do you load that file, for example in the `AppConfig`?

Comment: No I just tried the code above to try to get instance, Actually how to load file??

Comment: in the `AppConfig` of your app, see for example https://gist.github.com/kylefox/177091bd8e4d88ac0cc19496064fd7d3

Comment: I tried loading file in app.py but it did not work. I think is am missing something. Here is my file. 
**app.py :**
`from django.apps import AppConfig
class LogAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'log_app'
    def ready(self):
        import signals`

**signals.py :**
`from simple_history.signals import (pre_create_historical_record, post_create_historical_record)
@receiver(pre_create_historical_record)
def pre_create_historical_record_callback(sender, **kwargs):
    print("signal is running")
    history_instance = kwargs['history_instance']`

Comment: This should be `import app_name.signals`

Comment: You might want to add a `print(..)` statement in your `signals.py` file to ensure that it is properly loaded.

Comment: Yes i already have print statement in signals.py file and import is also changed still not working.

Comment: Thanks you for your help, I actually created signal function in models.py file and it worked.